# Efficiently setting all array values to zero

Tags: c++

I have not written C++ code in a while. I need to set all of the values in this program so far to 0 in an efficient manner.

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    double MainTrianglePoint1[2];
    double MainTrianglePoint2[2];
    double MainTrianglePoint3[2];
    std::cout << "Point 1 X:" << MainTrianglePoint1[2] << " Y:" << MainTrianglePoint1[1];
    std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Is there a loop I can perform on all of the `MainTrianglePoint` arrays so all of their values are set to 0?

Comment: You could easily initialize the arrays, or there's `std::fill`.

Answer (score 2):

With c++03, you can initialize the arrays directly in their declaration:

```
double MainTrianglePoint1[2] = {0,0};
```

With c++11 you can drop the `=` sign:

```
double MainTrianglePoint1[2] {0,0};
```

Comment: You could also drop `0,0`.

Comment: You could but I always prefer to clearly state to which values things are being initialized. It makes life easier if you want to set it to other values than the default. But I do agree that the "numberless" default version is useful when the size of the array is large.

Answer (score 1):

I consider to not use loop for that, you cat just fill memory by zeroes:

```
std::fill(std::begin(MainTrianglePoint1), std::end(MainTrianglePoint1), 0);
std::fill(std::begin(MainTrianglePoint2), std::end(MainTrianglePoint2), 0);
std::fill(std::begin(MainTrianglePoint3), std::end(MainTrianglePoint3), 0);
```

Comment: `std::fill` uses iterator, but for array it implemented in efficient manner, as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to do that.

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
  MainTrianglePoint1[i] = 0;
  MainTrianglePoint2[i] = 0;
  MainTrianglePoint2[i] = 0;
}
```

This will loop through each array index up to max size and set the value at the index to 0.

Answer (score 0):

May be you would want to create an unnamed structure and value initialize the members to its default value. [Demo](http://ideone.com/6rNWu1)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct  {

    double Point1[2];
    double Point2[2];
    double Point3[2];
} MainTriangle = {};
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Point 1 X:" << MainTriangle.Point1[2] << " Y:" << MainTriangle.Point1[1];
    std::cin.get();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can easily do this thing using {}. Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {

        double n[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                cout << n[i] << endl;
        }

        double k[10] {};

        cout << "-" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                cout << k[i] << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

[example](http://ideone.com/skFkmT)